# UIScrollView has White Space above SubViews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, scrollview

I am running across a weird issue, which I can't seem to figure out.
Upon adding multiple SubViews to a ScrollView, the ScrollViews keeps on adding a White Space ontop of the regular image

[image: White-Space ontop]

A bit better with more colors:
[image]

This is how it should look like:
[image: no white space]

The Image is perfectly scrollable.

This is the code I'm using to create the scrollview:

```
-(void)addImagesToScrollView
{
  if (self.product != nil)
  {
    int imageCount = 0;

    if (self.product.labelImage != nil)
    {
      UIImageView *labelImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
      labelImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.product.labelImage];
      labelImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      labelImage.tag = 100;
      [self.scrollView addSubview:labelImage];
      imageCount += 1;
    }

    if (self.product.bottleImage != nil)
    {
      UIImageView *bottleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
      bottleImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.product.bottleImage];
      bottleImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      bottleImage.tag = 101;
      imageCount += 1;

      [self.scrollView addSubview:bottleImage];
    }
    if (self.product.pourImage != nil)
    {
      UIImageView *pourImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
      pourImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.product.pourImage];
      pourImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      pourImage.tag = 102;
      imageCount += 1;
      [self.scrollView addSubview:pourImage];
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageCount, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

  }
}
```

Edit:

With a BackgroundColor:

[image: WIthBackgroundCOlor]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
bottleImage.layer.color = [UIcolor blueColor].CGColor; 
bottleImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```

It will let you see the frame of your UIImageView maybe you are calculating incorrectly the frame

Comment: Added that - seems like the Image is not stretching to the full extend?

Comment: Try UIViewContentModeScaleToFill

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and you will get desired output. In the following code you app will use album photos and automatically sets size of the scrolling as per the number of images in album. And please modify according to your image repository.

```
-(void)getAllPictures
{


    imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != nil) {
            if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
                [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

                NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]; 

                [library assetForURL:url
                         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                             [mutableArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];

                             if ([mutableArray count]==count)
                             {
                                 imageArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableArray];
                                 [self allPhotosCollected:imageArray];
                             }
                         }
                        failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!"); } ]; 

            } 
        }
    };

    NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            [assetGroups addObject:group];
            count=[group numberOfAssets];
        }
    };

    assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"There is an error");}];
}



-(void)allPhotosCollected:(NSArray*)imgArray
{


    CGSize imageSize;

    imageSize.width= imageView.bounds.size.width;
    imageSize.height = imageView.bounds.size.height;
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    self.scrollView.frame = imageView.frame;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * imgArray.count, imageSize.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.bounces=YES;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

    CGFloat xPos = 0.0;

    for (UIImage *image in imgArray) {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);


         [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        xPos += imageSize.width;
        // assuming ARC, otherwise release imageView

    }



}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20,320 , 420)];
    [self getAllPictures];
}
```